# Running caliper commandline

Tags: java, caliper

OK, again having some problems with caliper.

I am now running on Linux, trying to use the beta snapshot.  I am attempting to run Google's caliper via commandline using just the jar.  (Beta snapshot)

I *do not* have access to maven on this machine, and installing it is out of the question.  I would just like to use a jar and, maybe once this is working, I can write up a script or something.

Here is what I am doing:

1. Using small example Benchmark:

```java
import com.google.caliper.Benchmark;

public class Tutorial {

  public static class Benchmark1 {
    @Benchmark void timeNanoTime(int reps) {
      for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
        System.nanoTime();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Compile with `javac -cp caliper-1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT-all.jar Tutorial.java`

3. (Attempt to) run with

`java -cp caliper-1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT-all.jar com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain Tutorial.Benchmark1`, receive message `Benchmark class not found: Tutorial.Benchmark1`.

I've tried to work this out from bits and pieces of information from various sources but I am really having a heck of a time with this.  I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you really need no maven, this should work.

Your own class doesn't get found and I think it's a problem of your classpath. As they're usually more problem with nested classes try simply

```
java -cp caliper-1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT-all.jar com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain Tutorial
```

If the message changes to something like "class contains no benchmarks", then you'll know more. If you insists on using nested class, you may need to call `Tutorial$Benchmark1` (unprobable, but possible; java class naming is sick).

Please try also

```
java -cp caliper-1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT-all.jar Tutorial.Benchmark1
```

to see if your class lies on the classpath (the message should change to something like "no main method").

See also [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193140/how-to-use-caliper-benchmark-beta-snapshot-without-maven).

Comment: I've tried variations on Tutorial (Tutorial$Benchmark1.class and so on) and none of them work.  I've attempted un-nesting the class as well.  For the record, the jar and the compiled class are sharing a directory.

The second command results in "could not find the main class."  I don't understand why Tutorial is apparently invisible... is it looking exclusively in the jar?  How can I ensure that it's on the classpath?

Comment: Actually, got it.  You were right, it was a classpath issue.  Ended up doing `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jar:.` and running `java com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain Tutorial` from the directory including the .class files...   It's finding the class fine.  It still doesn't work, mind, as it crashes with no output, but at it's technically running.

Comment: @KristineRichard: No output at all? That's strange. Maybe `-v` could help, no idea. I couldn't find the tutorial you're using, so I can't try it out. Maybe you could create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) the form of a ZIP file?

Comment: Well, not "none at all" (sorry) but after downloading and rebuilding the newest revision I actually get some results - I think the issue had been fixed in January.  There is a problem with crashes during allocation measurement but the runtime testing works fine so far and that's enough for me at the moment.  I'm no longer held up, and I submitted an issue re: other crashes.